# Creacion de Docker con PhpDocumentor

Tags: php, docker

estoy tratando de crear un docker con la imagen de phpdoc de docker hub, el caso es que sigo las instrucciones que hay en la propia página que son las siguientes:

1. $ docker pull phpdoc/phpdoc
2. $ docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/data phpdoc/phpdoc

Al ejecutar el segundo comando me crea un contenedor de forma que no puedo acceder a el, ese es el primer problema.
El segundo problema es que como ultimo paso, ejecute el siguiente comando.
3. phpdoc run -d <SOURCE_DIRECTORY> -t <TARGET_DIRECTORY>

Al hacerlo me muestra un error como de que el comando phpdoc no existe. Mi pregunta es, como genero entonces la documentacion de la aplicacion de php?

Gracias de antemano.